# Where will the output file goes when we do "kill -3 <pid>"

Tags: java, unix, jboss, pid, thread-dump

I want to understand what went wrong with the running process in Jboss. So I did `kill -3 <pid>`, but I was not able to fing the thread dump file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending a SIGQUIT (aka 'kill -3') to JBoss (or any Java process) will output the current thread dump to console.  In particular, you want to be running JBoss in the foreground, looking at shell you launched it in.  Then thread dump should be shown in the console when you send a kill -3 (from another shell).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following. The thread dump will be redirected to output_file.

```
jstack <pid> > output_file
```